# Minimise $\sum_i \begin{Vmatrix}\boldsymbol{x}_i \\ \boldsymbol{y}_i\end{Vmatrix}$

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

Consider column vectors $\boldsymbol{z}_i$,  $\quad i=1,\dots,n$.
Each $\boldsymbol{z}_i$ has $j$ elements and can be expressed as $\boldsymbol{z}_i = \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_i \\ \boldsymbol{y}_i  \end{bmatrix}$ where by $\boldsymbol{x}_i$ and $\boldsymbol{y}_i$ are the first $k$ and last $j-k$ elements respectively.

Given $\boldsymbol{y}_1,\boldsymbol{y}_2,\dots,\boldsymbol{y}_n$, find $\boldsymbol{x}_1,\boldsymbol{x}_2,\dots,\boldsymbol{x}_n$ such that $\sum_i \| \boldsymbol{z}_i \| $ is minimised and $\sum_i \boldsymbol{x}_i = \boldsymbol{c}$ for some $k$-element column vector $\boldsymbol{c}$.

In words: Minimise the sum of lengths of a set of vectors {$\boldsymbol{z}_i$}. Each vector $\boldsymbol{z}_i$, has some fixed elements $\boldsymbol{y}_i$ and some variable elements $\boldsymbol{x}_i$. Each of the variable elements has a fixed sum across the vectors expressed as $\sum_i \boldsymbol{x}_i = \boldsymbol{c}$. This could also be written $\sum_i x_{i,m} = c_m$ for each element $m$.

The solution is $\boldsymbol{x}_i = \boldsymbol{c} \frac{\| \boldsymbol{y}_i \|}{  \overline{\|\boldsymbol{y}\|} } \quad $ where $\overline{\|\boldsymbol{y}\|}=\sum_i{\|\boldsymbol{y}_i\|}$.

In words: The minimum total length is achieved by apportioning the variable components among the vectors in the ratio of the lengths of the fixed components.

The problem can be solved with Lagrange multipliers.

Question:  Is there a simpler solution?
Can it be solved with matrix algebra alone? It feels similar to the least-squares regression matrix formula.

Comment: I voted to put this on hold, but this could be a reasonable question for MO, after an edit makes the question clearer; don't be discouraged by the (temporary) closure.

Comment: Hope this helps. All straight lines are vector lengths, not component-wise absolute values.

Comment: It does help, thanks! So $|v|$ is the Euclidean norm of $v$, $(\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|^2)^{1/2}$? This is usually denoted with double bars, $\|v\|$. In particular, do you confirm that you sum lengths, not squared lengths (which would make the question a lot easier)?

Comment: Yes, Euclidean norm. Sorry didn't realise I needed double bars. Unfortunately it is lengths not squared lengths.

Comment: A first simplification is that you can assume that $j-k=1$, by replacing $\boldsymbol{y}_i$ with the scalar $\|\boldsymbol{y}_i\|$.

Comment: Federico, thanks for adding the double bars. I was going to do that this morning. I've made two more changes. One in the heading and moving the over-bar outside the double bars for the sum of y. Feel free to change back.   Yes agree $j-k=1$ makes it simpler and doesn't affect the result.

Comment: For the simplest case, $k=1,j=2,n=2$, there is a standard trick from math Olympiad literature which is reformulation as sum of distances: the polygonal line that connects $A = (0,0)$, $B = (x_1,y_1)$ and the fixed point $C = (x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2) = (c,y_1+y_2)$ has length equal to the objective function, and by the triangle inequality it is minimized when one chooses $x_1$ so that the three points are aligned. Maybe I am missing some crucial details, but it looks like the idea can be generalized to higher $j$ (working one dimension at a time) and $n$ (working with more than three points).

Comment: Yes, I am now convinced that my comments produce a full answer: (1) reduce to $j-k=1$ as above, then (2) reformulate as $\min dist(0,z_1)+ dist(z_1,z_1+z_2) + dist(z_1+z_2,z_1+z_2+z_3) + \dots + dist(z_1+\dots+z_{n-1}, z_1+\dots+z_n)$, where the last point does not depend on the $x_i$ (3) apply triangle inequality to conclude that the points must be aligned. I can write it down in more detail if the question gets reopened (currently it has 4 votes, and I think 5 are needed).

Answer (score 1):

Converted from my comments. The first observation is that you can assume the $y_i$ to be nonnegative scalars: indeed, you can replace $y_i$ with $\|y_i\|$ without changing the problem.

Then, the thesis follows from the triangle inequality. Indeed,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|z_1\| + \|z_2\| + \dots + \|z_n\| &\geq \|z_1 + z_2 + \dots + z_n\| \\ & = \left\|\begin{bmatrix}c \\ \overline{y}\end{bmatrix}\right\| \\&= \left\|\begin{bmatrix}c\frac{y_1}{\overline{y}} \\ y_1\end{bmatrix} + \dots + \begin{bmatrix}c\frac{y_n}{\overline{y}} \\ y_n\end{bmatrix} \right\|
\\&= \left\|\begin{bmatrix}c\frac{y_1}{\overline{y}} \\ y_1\end{bmatrix}\right\| + \dots + \left\|\begin{bmatrix}c\frac{y_n}{\overline{y}} \\ y_n\end{bmatrix} \right\|.
\end{aligned}
$$
with $\overline{y} = y_1 + y_2 + \dots + y_n$. The last equality holds because all the vectors in the last expression are nonnegative scalar multiples of $\begin{bmatrix}c\frac{1}{\overline{y}} \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.

(If $\overline{y}=0$, then you can take any partition of $1$ in place of the quantiieis $\frac{y_i}{\overline{y}}$ and the proof works in the same way.)

The geometric idea behind this proof is the following: let $k=j-k=1$ for simplicity, so that we are on the plane. You wish to travel from the point $(0,0)$ to $(c,\overline{y})$, and you are allowed to move along a polygonal line that bends only in points with ordinates $y_1, y_1+y_2,\dots, y_1+y_2+\dots+y_{n-1}$. Then, clearly, the shortest path is a straight line, making no bends.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Federico :)